# Angularjs generic directive and DOM manipulation

Tags: angularjs

I have a `Directive` that I want it to be **generic** to the application. 
And I'd like to know if it is a good practice to do DOM manipulation inside the `Controller` if not please could you explain where I'am supposed to do it.

Should I create a service like **MyDirectiveUIService** or something similar to externalize all DOM manipulation..?

Thank you

**My app looks like this**

In the template I call `myDirective` and `myFunction`

```
<div my-directive my-function="myFunction()"></div>
```

Then `myDirective` call `myFunction` in the `link` function

```
myApp.directive( 'myDirective', function() {

    function link( scope, element, attributes ) {
        scope.myFunction(element)
    }

    return {
        scope:{
            myFunction:'&'
        },
        link:link
    }
}
```

In all the controllers where I use the directive I have the function definition as

```
$scope.myFunction = function(element){
    //DIFFERENT DOM MANIPULATION FOR EACH CONTROLLERS  
}
```

Comment: Directives are meant for DOM manipulations. What you are doing here is just delegating a function to controller. The directive is not needed for this. If you have varying DOM manipulations without any pattern, you need to use separate directive for each. Your syntax for directive is also not correct. You need to include the link in the return object too.

Comment: yes right for the link, I forgot to add it in the example. So you are saying that I have use separate directives even if the directive is very big and do a lot of things and Just need some small alteration like sometimes do something and sometimes not

Comment: You are missing the point. Directives should be highly specific. Like displaying a carousel. If you want to display a carousel and probably use a dropdown too, you'll be better off with two different directives. I suggest you re-structure what you are trying to accomplish. A directive shouldn't need to do many things.